# Reformat datetime variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, datetime, format

I have the following `datetime` `2014-02-05 17:12:48` stored in a `php` variable named `$reportDb["reportDate"]`.

Now, It is in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format, I want it in `d/m/Y H:i:s` format. How can I set or reformat this variable?

I tried with `datetime::createformat` but It doesn't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$formatted = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($reportDb["reportDate"]))
```

If you want another method. Even if i would prefer the one already mentioned.

Output `05/02/2014 17:12:48`

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3 and older:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2014-02-05 17:12:48');
echo $dt->format(''d/m/Y H:i:s'');
```

PHP 5.4+:

```
$dt = (new DateTime('2014-02-05 17:12:48'))->format(''d/m/Y H:i:s'');
```

with the variable:

```
$dt = (new DateTime($reportDb["reportDate"]))->format(''d/m/Y H:i:s'');
```

Comment: 2014-02-05 17:12:48 is stored in a variable and always it will change.

Comment: So put the variable in the DateTime call

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR.

Comment: You must be running an older version of PHP. Try the updated code I provided.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right, $reportDb["reportDate"] is already a DateTime object.

If so, all you need is ...

```
$reportDb["reportDate"]->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Cheers!

Comment: It doesnt works and produce the following error: 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object'

Comment: The $reportDb["reportDate"] has to be a DateTime object. PHP is telling you that it is NOT an object. Therefore, update your question because "datetime 2014-02-05 17:12:48" is not a DateTime, is a string. In that case John Conde's answer is the right one.